# Is there any nodejs project to wrap svn command?

Tags: node.js, svn

Is there any nodejs project to wrap svn command? Such as: do update/commit change.

Comment: There are a few [published `svn` projects](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/svn), but they either don't really appear to be that far along in what they support or are simply aimed at being *read-only* (parsing logs, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I've published a project named [svn-spawn](https://npmjs.org/package/svn-spawn) on npmjs.

It's a thin wrapper on svn command.

Usage example:

```js
var Client = require('svn-spawn');
var client = new Client({
    cwd: '/path to your svn working directory'
});

// svn up
client.update(function(err, data) {
    console.log('updated');
});

// svn commit
client.commit('commit message here', function(err, data) {
    console.log('done');
});

// any other svn commands
client.cmd(['revert', 'dir1', '--depth', 'infinity'], function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: it need to depend your local "svn command", any other choice that no need to install svn locally?